# Add observer to shared library

Tags: c++, dll, dependencies, shared-libraries, observer-pattern

In my current implementation I have a shared library (`CameraControl.dll` - used with implicit linking) which when triggered takes pictures and saves them in a local storage.

The new functionality I'm trying to implement requires to get the picture when the camera was triggered and send it to another app for processing using a `REST API` (most likely).

So I was thinking to use an observer pattern and basically in the shared library API `(CameraControl.dll)` I would just add a `RegisterObserver` method where I can register the new app which will be notified when a new picture is taken and will grab the picture from the local storage and send it further for processing.

This would mean to add a common dependency to an abstract Observer class between the `CameraControl.dll` and the new app that will register itself as an observer.

Can I achieve this in a better way (better design). I feel that having a common dependency between the dll and another application is not ok and maybe does not justify using a shared library anymore.

Comment: This sounds a little "opinions based" tbh. Perhaps, at its simplest, only  callback function might do? The only "common dependency" then would be the callback function signature.

Comment: Yeap using a callback seems like a good solution also. Thanks.